# Error in meta-data in android manifest while integrating firebase_admob

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I am using the

```
firebase_admob: ^0.11.0+1
```

I added the meta-data in the manifest file as follows (in the last):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.aa_store">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="AA Store"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <provider
    android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="here I used my admob id like ca-app-pub- and so"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

While building the app I am getting the following error message in the debug console.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3159b380b6099786f8f1e3b5a96c779b\play-services-ads-lite-19.7.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-43:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 26s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin connectivity...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'connectivity'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s

Exception: The plugin connectivity could not be built due to the issue above.

I also added the google-services json file in the app level griddle.
Please anyone help me to resolve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday i got the same error while adding firebase_admob.
In my case, i updated this

from :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

to :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

in my android/build.gradle, and it worked perfectly!